# How do I echo selected items in a do- while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, select

I am beginner in PHP. In edit section I have defined a Do-While loop to get the information from data base. But when the user choose from the drop-down and submit
the selected item disappears and fist option appears on drop-down. How Can I retrieve and echo selected items after submitting.

```
<?php
  $cat_sql= "SELECT * FROM cars";
        $cat_sql_query=mysql_query($cat_sql);
        $cat_sql_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($cat_sql_query);
?>

<form action="MSPEditstock.php" method="POST">
<span style="font-size: 18px; margin:10px;">Please Choose your car from the dropdown:</span>
  <select id="sortmethod" name="editstock" >
  <?php do{?>
  <option value="<?php echo $cat_sql_row['id']; ?>"  > <?php echo $cat_sql_row['Brand'].$cat_sql_row['Model'];?> </option>
  <?php ; }while($cat_sql_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($cat_sql_query))?>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Start Editting" class="fvisual">
</form>
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the javascript. It sounds like client side changing it after rendering.

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you wish for the value selected by a user before submitting the form to be selected in the dropdown menu once the page has reloaded? Hopefully the following will give an idea as to how you could achieve that.

```
<?php
    $cat_sql= "SELECT * FROM cars";
        $cat_sql_query=mysql_query( $cat_sql );
        $cat_sql_row=mysql_fetch_assoc( $cat_sql_query );

    $editstock=!empty( $_POST['editstock'] ) ? $_POST['editstock'] : false;
?>

<form action="MSPEditstock.php" method="POST">
    <span style="font-size: 18px; margin:10px;">Please Choose your car from the dropdown:</span>
    <select id="sortmethod" name="editstock" >
        <?php

        while( $cat_sql_row=mysql_fetch_assoc( $cat_sql_query ) ){

            $id=$cat_sql_row['id'];
            $brand=$cat_sql_row['Brand'];
            $model=$cat_sql_row['Model'];
            $selected=$editstock && $editstock==$id ? ' selected ' : '';

            echo "<option value='{$id}'{$selected}>{$brand}{$model}";
        }

        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Start Editting" class="fvisual">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code. Unfortunately, the last item in drop-down is displayed after submitting not the choice which the user selects. :(

Comment: ah - silly me I forget the bit that tests to see if the current id in the loop is equal to that posted!

Comment: Thanks again for your time. But do you think there is a way to solve the issue?

Comment: I did make a minor edit already, namely `$selected=$editstock && $editstock==$id ? ' selected ' : '';`